# How can i get response from json by sending these parameters?

Tags: android-json

how can i send these json sample parameters to get data? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
{
    "request" : "2015-03-19 12:15:34",
    "msisdn" : "9199620*****",
    "key" : "XYZ123",
    "id" : "ABC123",
    "category" : "chennai",
    "date" : "2015-03-18",
}
```

Url = `http://www.prakash.com/m*****/j****`

Answer (score 0):

If you want all these values, than below code will fix your problem

```
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(response);
if(obj != null) {
    String request = obj.getString("request");
    String msisdn= obj.getString("msisdn");
    String key= obj.getString("key");
    String id= obj.getString("id");
    String category= obj.getString("category");
    String date = obj.getString("date");
}
```